# ERROR:Game.update() failure Slick 2D collision detection

Tags: java, collision-detection, slick2d

I'm working with slick2D to create a test game and right now I'm doing hit detection using rectangles and the intersects method.
I created two rectangles for each platform the player comes in contact with; one used to see if the player is hitting the platform from the sides or bottom and another one pixel tall rectangle that is used to see if the character is standing on the platform.

The problem is if I add anything that hast to do with a plattop (the one pixel long rectangles) to the update class like say:

```
if(playplathit.intersects(plat1top))
{
    falling = false;
}
```

when you enter the state that the platforms are in you get this error:

```
Fri Dec 13 22:57:31 EST 2013 ERROR:Game.update() failure - check the game code.
org.newdawn.slick.SlickException: Game.update() failure - check the game code.
at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(Ga meContainer.java:669)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGam eContainer.java:411)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameCo ntainer.java:321)
at javagame.Game.main(Game.java:34)
```

My guess is that I'm some how overloading Java or Slick. I'm also convinced I'm doing hit detection in the worst possible way as I'm not following a guide.
Here is the code without any plattop if statements in the update class:

```
public class Play extends BasicGameState
{
    int[] duration = {200,200};
    float playerX = 100;
    float playerY = 353;
    float screenX = 0;
    float screenY = 0;
    float plat1X = 0;
    float plat2X = 174;
    float plat3X = 461;
    float plat4X = 618;
    float plat5X = 881;
    float plat6X = 1233;
    float plat7X = 1438;
    float plat8X = 1754;
    float vertspd = 0.0f;
    Animation playeranistart, idleani, runforani, runbackani, jumpani;
    boolean falling;
    boolean jumping;
    boolean rightside = false;
    boolean leftside = false;
    Rectangle playplathit, plat1, plat2, plat3, plat4, plat5, plat6, plat7, plat8, plat1top, plat2top, plat3top, plat4top, plat5top, plat6top, plat7top, plat8top;
    public Play(int state)
    {

    }
    public void player()
    {

    }

    public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException
    {
        Image[] idle = {new Image("res/player.png"), new Image("res/player.png")};
        idleani = new Animation(idle,duration,false);
        Image[] startidle = {new Image("res/player.png"), new Image("res/player.png")};
        playeranistart = new Animation(startidle,duration,false);
        Image[] run1 = {new Image("res/playerrun1.png"), new Image("res/playerrun1.png")};
        runforani = new Animation(run1,duration,false);
        Image[] run2 = {new Image("res/playerrun2.png"), new Image("res/playerrun2.png")};
        runbackani = new Animation(run2,duration,false);

    }
    public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException
    {
        Image lvl1 = new Image("res/testlvl.png");
        playplathit = new Rectangle(playerX, playerY, 15, 39);
        plat1 = new Rectangle(plat1X, 393, 597, 8);
        plat1top = new Rectangle(plat1X, 392, 597, 1);
        plat2 = new Rectangle(plat2X, 325, 247, 5);
        plat2top = new Rectangle(plat2X, 324, 247, 1);
        plat3 = new Rectangle(plat3X, 265, 78, 6);
        plat3top = new Rectangle(plat3X, 264, 78, 1);
        plat4 = new Rectangle(plat4X, 232, 141, 5);
        plat4top = new Rectangle(plat4X, 231, 141, 1);
        plat5 = new Rectangle(plat5X, 393, 755, 8);
        plat5top = new Rectangle(plat5X, 392, 755, 1);
        plat6 = new Rectangle(plat6X, 357, 214, 44);
        plat6top = new Rectangle(plat6X, 356, 214, 1);
        plat7 = new Rectangle(plat7X, 330, 219, 70);
        plat7top = new Rectangle(plat7X, 329, 219, 1);
        plat8 = new Rectangle(plat8X, 393, 243, 8);
        plat8top = new Rectangle(plat8X, 392, 243, 1);
        g.drawImage(lvl1, screenX,screenY);
        playeranistart.draw(playerX,playerY);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.draw(playplathit);
        g.draw(plat1);
        g.draw(plat2);
        g.draw(plat3);
        g.draw(plat4);
        g.draw(plat5);
        g.draw(plat6);
        g.draw(plat7);
        g.draw(plat8);
        g.draw(plat1top);
        g.draw(plat2top);
        g.draw(plat3top);
        g.draw(plat4top);
        g.draw(plat5top);
        g.draw(plat6top);
        g.draw(plat7top);
        g.draw(plat8top);
    }
    public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException
    {
         Input input = gc.getInput();

         if(jumping == false)
         {
             vertspd = 0;
         }
         if((input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_D) == false) || (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_A) == false)|| (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_W) == false))
         {
             playeranistart = idleani;
         }
         if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_D))
         {
             screenX = screenX - 3.3f;
             plat1X = plat1X - 3.3f;
             plat2X = plat2X - 3.3f;
             plat3X = plat3X - 3.3f;
             plat4X = plat4X - 3.3f;
             plat5X = plat5X - 3.3f;
             plat6X = plat6X - 3.3f;
             plat7X = plat7X - 3.3f;
             plat8X = plat8X - 3.3f;
             playeranistart = runforani;
             if(playplathit.intersects(plat1) || playplathit.intersects(plat2) || playplathit.intersects(plat3) || playplathit.intersects(plat4) || playplathit.intersects(plat5) || playplathit.intersects(plat6) || playplathit.intersects(plat7) || playplathit.intersects(plat8))
             {
                 if(rightside)
                 {
                     plat1X = plat1X - 3.3f;
                     plat2X = plat2X - 3.3f;
                     plat3X = plat3X - 3.3f;
                     plat4X = plat4X - 3.3f;
                     plat5X = plat5X - 3.3f;
                     plat6X = plat6X - 3.3f;
                     plat7X = plat7X - 3.3f;
                     plat8X = plat8X - 3.3f;
                     screenX = screenX - 3.3f;
                     rightside = false;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     plat1X = plat1X + 3.3f;
                     plat2X = plat2X + 3.3f;
                     plat3X = plat3X + 3.3f;
                     plat4X = plat4X + 3.3f;
                     plat5X = plat5X + 3.3f;
                     plat6X = plat6X + 3.3f;
                     plat7X = plat7X + 3.3f;
                     plat8X = plat8X + 3.3f;
                     screenX = screenX + 3.3f; 
                     leftside = true;
                 }
             }
         }
         if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_A))
         {
             playeranistart = runbackani;
             plat1X = plat1X + 3.3f;
             plat2X = plat2X + 3.3f;
             plat3X = plat3X + 3.3f;
             plat4X = plat4X + 3.3f;
             plat5X = plat5X + 3.3f;
             plat6X = plat6X + 3.3f;
             plat7X = plat7X + 3.3f;
             plat8X = plat8X + 3.3f;
             screenX = screenX + 3.3f;
             if(playplathit.intersects(plat1) || playplathit.intersects(plat2) || playplathit.intersects(plat3) || playplathit.intersects(plat4) || playplathit.intersects(plat5) || playplathit.intersects(plat6) || playplathit.intersects(plat7) || playplathit.intersects(plat8))
             {

                 if(leftside)
                 {
                     plat1X = plat1X + 3.3f;
                     plat2X = plat2X + 3.3f;
                     plat3X = plat3X + 3.3f;
                     plat4X = plat4X + 3.3f;
                     plat5X = plat5X + 3.3f;
                     plat6X = plat6X + 3.3f;
                     plat7X = plat7X + 3.3f;
                     plat8X = plat8X + 3.3f;
                     screenX = screenX + 3.3f;
                     leftside = false;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     plat1X = plat1X - 3.3f;
                     plat2X = plat2X - 3.3f;
                     plat3X = plat3X - 3.3f;
                     plat4X = plat4X - 3.3f;
                     plat5X = plat5X - 3.3f;
                     plat6X = plat6X - 3.3f;
                     plat7X = plat7X - 3.3f;
                     plat8X = plat8X - 3.3f;
                     screenX = screenX - 3.3f;
                     rightside = true;
                 }
             }
         }
         if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_W))
         {
             if(jumping != true)
             {
                 vertspd = 1.0f * (delta);
                 playerY = playerY - vertspd;

             }   
         }
    }
    public int getID()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.

Comment: Which line is line 34 in your program?  trying to trace the error

Comment: Also please place all the code that you used when you got the error you reported into ur example.  It's hard to help when you don't have all the info :p

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry that i was stupid enough to put in code that did not have the error. This is working code. I thought that it did not matter because is include any if statement anywhere in the update class it gives me that error.

Comment: It may or may not matter.  My intuition is that the SlickException is being thrown because of concurrent modification.  However it is hard to tell without knowing how the slick2D source code works (I'm not that familiar with it)

Comment: One thing I do see that is wrong, is that you are initializing an image in the Render method. This is bad, as the render method cannot do heavy logic on the UI thread that slick uses. Try making that image a global var and initialize it in the init method rather than the render method. There's no reason to grab that resource hundreds and hundreds of times each fps tick. (this also goes for the Rectangles you are making. Update their coordinates with .setX() rather than re-initializing and making whole new objects over and over.)